# How can i write a test using React Testing Library to check if hover changes the components style?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, jest-dom

I am testing my application and encountered a problem. When trying to test whether a row in my `Dropdown` component applies an effect on hover, I noticed I was not able to check elements for their background color, which I find odd.

Trying to use the jest-dom matcher `"toHaveStyle()"`, the following is an example where I cannot for the life of me get it to work.

**dropdown.test.tsx**

```
test('Should contain clickable elements that change style when hovered', () => {
    const dropElement1 = screen.getByLabelText('testLabel1');
    expect(dropElement1).toHaveStyle('background: white');
});
```

**Error**

[image: Error]

I have also tried this by using `background-color`, by using the hex value (another interesting bug is that PrettyDom converts hex to RGB), or by adding to the declaration in `toHaveStyle()`.

I am certain that the element is indeed white, and I can't understand what is going wrong. If my approach is bad practice and you have a better idea of how to check this, or you have a solution to my problem, please, let me know!

Comment: Could you please provide the code for the component under test?

Answer (score 3):

Your testing case can't find the `dropElement1` style because it's a drop-down menu and has not opened since you just render the `Dropdown` component.

You need to simulate a **mouse hover** or **clicking** action on the `DropDown` menu and then expect to have a styles property for it.

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, fireEvent, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Dropdown } from "./Dropdown";

test('Should contain clickable elements that change style when hovered', async () => {
    render(<Dropdown />);
    
    fireEvent.mouseEnter(screen.getByText('drop-down-btn'));
    
    await waitFor(() => screen.getByTestId('dropdown-menu'))

    expect(screen.getByLabelText('testLabel1')).toHaveStyle('background: white');
});
```

**Note:** As you have not posted the `Dropdown` component, I put some sample names for getting your toggles and drop-down menu. Also, you can read about the mouse events on the [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-events/). You can also use `mouseOver` but it depends on your drop-down menu implementation.